# How to sort a list that could contain null values with dart null-safety

Tags: flutter, sorting, dart, dart-null-safety

I have a list of strings that may contain null values, how do I sort this list?

I'm using **Flutter beta channel** so **null-safety** is checked. This is what I have so far:

```
List<String?> _list = [
  
 'beta',
 'fotxtrot',
 'alpha',
  null,
  null, 
 'delta',
];

_list.sort((a, b) => a!.compareTo(b!));
```

How do I get this as the outcome:

```
_list = [
  null,
  null,
  'alpha',
  'beta',
  'delta',
  'fotxtrot',
];
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I encountered this recently and built a one line function based on [compareTo documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.5/dart-core/num/compareTo.html):

```
myList.sort((a, b) => a==null ? 1: b==null? -1 : a.compareTo(b));
```

NB: This brings the null value at the end of the list. In your case just swap -1 and 1 to have them at the front of your List.

Answer (score 5):

You need to modify your sorting method to handle nullable values, not just ignore them. After handling potential nulls you can compare them normally.

```dart
_list.sort((a, b) {
  if(a == null) {
    return -1;
  }
  if(b == null) {
    return 1;
  }
  return a.compareTo(b);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `whereType`:

```dart
List<String?> _list = [
  'c',
  'a',
  'd',
  null,
  null,
  'b',
];

void main() {
  var list = _list.whereType<String>().toList();
  list.sort();
  print(list); // [a, b, c, d]
}
```